# Too many parameters passed to query: {"currentStock" :#}

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am new to Mongo & Ws02 DSS. Below is the update operation I have written to update the existing document in the Mcongo's llection named "inventory".

```html
 <query id="mongoUpdate" useConfig="localMongo1">
      <expression>inventory.update({"itemId":"3"},{"currentStock" :"2"})</expression>
     <param name="itemId" sqlType="STRING"/>
 </query>
```

While all the simple operations works well, but I am getting the below nested exception for update :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many parameters passed to query: {"currentStock" :"2"}

For simplicity, I have hard corded without using the param I have created, but still the update doesn't work. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you show the result of a get query?

Comment: > db.inventory.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("596e79ad60b934a369266524"), "itemId" : "1", "itemName" : "Television-4k", "unitPrice" : "1400", "currentStock" : "77" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("596e79bf60b934a369266525"), "itemId" : "2", "itemName" : "Laptop", "unitPrice" : "400", "currentStock" : "53" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("596e7dad7353e34606463c37"), "itemId" : "4", "itemName" : "Refrigerator", "unitPrice" : "700", "currentStock" : "23" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("596ef6327353e33b264b506c"), "itemId" : "3", "itemName" : "Mobile", "unitPrice" : "400", "currentStock" : "2" }

Comment: Adding the query :     <query id="inventory_find" useConfig="inventory_ds">    <expression>inventory.find()</expression>
      <result element="items" rowName="item"><element column="document.itemId" name="itemId" xsdType="integer"/>
         <element column="document.itemName" name="itemName" xsdType="string"/><element column="document.unitPrice" name="unitPrice" xsdType="string"/><element column="document.currentStock" name="currentStock" xsdType="string"/>  </result>   </query>
And Operation :  <operation name="listAllItems">
      <call-query href="inventory_find"/>
   </operation>

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove `<param name="itemId" sqlType="STRING"/>` part?

Comment: When i remove the param from the query & operations's call-query, the hard coded update is working well. Only when i use params, it is throwing "Too many parameters passed to query: {currentStock : '3'}". 
<query id="inventory_stockUpdate" useConfig="inventoryMongo">
      <expression>inventory.update({itemId:'3'}, {currentStock : '3'})</expression>
      <param name="itemId" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>

i am not sure why it is.

Comment: Please post your original query config. (i.e. with parameter)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I think.

```
<query id="mongoUpdate" useConfig="localMongo1">
    <expression>inventory.update({"itemId":#},{"currentStock" :"2"}, true))</expression>
     <param name="itemId" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>
```